# How to remove duplicate entries within the Open With Other Application menu?

Tags: wine, appmenu

Whenever I try to open a file with an application , i found different than default programs duplicated entries :

[image: Open With Other Application menu]

How to remove duplicated entries?

Comment: Why did you added the tag `wine`?

Comment: @Lucio That is because I noted that the duplicated entries are only wine entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete the multiple entries (you will see a lot of **wine** entries) in

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

[image]

When you finish , see if the duplicated open with programs has gone .

Comment: How to determine which are the ones that I want to remove?

Comment: i had this problem , i removed them all , then add every program when i need it.

Comment: Don't miss understand me, but: **How do I add them?** I don't want to commit any irreversible mistake when deleting them all.

Comment: can you screenshot the duplicated entries

Comment: i will give you a link wait how to add any program to open with but i remember when i deleted them nothing get wrong

Comment: Like [this](http://postimg.org/image/ubnnocr3x/) you say?

Comment: yes i only delete 170 but be aware only wine if there is other don't delete them

Comment: i had a list mimeapps.list i didnt delete it just wine entries

Comment: ok, It worked but know I need to know which ones have I to keep. I guess that got to be on my own, Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome my friend :) happy to help you anytime